# Sum function of a column value not returning a sum value but instead a singular array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that as a numerical value in a column,
when I try code below as:

```
df['numbers'].sum()
```

instead of sum of that column it returns below:

[image]

the column the sum is being run on is a Dtype object column.

Do I have to convert column Dtype so sum can run correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cast to the type integer before sum:

```
df['numbers'].astype(int).sum()
```

Comment: when i try this - I get error of 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,033'